# How to avoid optional checks in Swift UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, option-type

I've noticed an annoying pattern in iOS code. View controllers are passed parameters from a previous view controller, after the new view controller is instantiated, so you end up with code like the example below. Properties of `SecondViewController` are really not optional, but they have to be nullable because you set them in `prepare(for:sender:)`.

```
class FirstController : UIViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        ...
        let vc = segue.destination as! SecondController
        vc.thing = getThing()
        vc.abc = "123"
        ...

class SecondController : UIViewController {
    var thing: Thing?
    var abc: String?
    override func viewDidLoad() { ... }
    func foo() {
        guard let thing = self.thing else { return }
        ...
    }
    func bar() {
        blahBlah(abc!)
```

It seems there are two options with the instance variables...

1. Make them `T?` and have `guard` or `if let` everywhere.
2. Make them v `T!` and hope nothing gets called before they are set.

So maybe my question boils down to this: is it safe to do #2 here? Is there a guarantee that nothing is called on the `UIViewController` before `prepare(for:sender:)` in the first controller?

**Edit:** One reason I don't like option 1 as much is that it leads to `guards` in almost every method, when they are probably unnecessary. Seems like a code smell to me. In a pure Swift class you would pass `thing` and `abc` to `init(...)`, and they'd be non-optional, but you can't do that here. We're dealing with a odd situation where Swift has been added to something that was designed in Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically speaking, yes if you set all those variables before the prepare then It should be fine. But what's wrong with using guard and lets everywhere? It's just the way swift is. And even if it is safe to do number 2 now who's to say it won't be safe in the future? Or some weird behaviour we don't know occurs and it isn't actually safe or maybe you have someone else working on the project as well and they didn't know of this and forget to set one of the variables before segueing and it ends up causing a crash. Hence, number 1 is by far the safest route to go and you can rest with an ease of mind knowing it won't crash because of that.

Comment: Keep in mind that you might want it to crash because it means there is a bug in the code. Using option #2 may be better because you don't need all of the checks and if the app crashes (during development and/or testing, then that's good because you found a bug in your app).

Comment: @rmaddy that's a very fair point and I agree. However for release I would definitely not want to use option 2. Especially if you have thousands of users using your app you can never be sure what will happen, combine that with multiple developers coding in the project and you got yourself a headache.

Comment: What does release have to do with it? If your app has been tested with option 2 and it works properly, then it is the correct solution. If you release it and it suddenly breaks due to option 2 then you did a lousy job testing. It's still a bug in your code that needs to be fixed. It doesn't mean using option 2 was wrong.

Comment: @rmaddy Not necessarily, if you have a very large code base with multiple developers and you're dealing with complex problems then would you not want to use the safest method? What is wrong with using option number 1? Because we don't like the way guards and if let statements look? Because we want to catch fatal crashes during release? If your code base is very large and there's very array of complex problems being solved then it's naive and impracctical to think that you can catch every single bug during the testing phase.

Comment: I added to the question to explain why I'm not entirely happy with option 1.